# Cost of re-entering synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization

**Question:** What is the cost of re-entering a synchronized block when the monitor is already locked?

For example:

```
Object lock;
void outer()
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {
        innerOne();
        innerTwo();
    }
}

void innerOne() { synchronized (lock) { /* ... */ } }
void innerTwo() { synchronized (lock) { /* ... */ } }
```

The intention of the above is that `innerOne` and `innerTwo` are always called while the thread is synchronised on `lock`.

If there is a non-negligible cost is there any method that can be called to put in an `assert` statement?  The closest I can find is to call `lock.notify()`, and catch `IllegalMonitorStateException`, e.g.

```
boolean isMonitorHeld(final Object object)
{
    try { object.notify(); return true }
    catch (final IllegalMonitorStateException e) { return false; }
}
```

Which would be used like:

```
void innerOne() { assert isMonitorHeld(lock); /* ... */ }
```

Are there any comments on the style of the two options, or any alternatives?

**EDIT**

I'm hoping for more comprehensive answers than just 'time it and see'.  I don't have the ability to foresee all of the potential situations my code could encounter and then even create a test to exhibit these situations.  I'd like to understand how the synchronisation mechanism works to understand how it might perform in different circumstances.  I understand synchronisation may be implemented differently on the different platforms.  In which case is it different (primarily on Solaris and Linux OSes)?

Intuitively, I don't believe that re-entering a synchronised block will have a noticeable cost as most of the articles I can find imply that uncontended locks are cheap.  However, it doesn't feel right to add the synchronised blocks in these methods as it gives the impression they can be called *without* having first synchronised on the lock.  The assert gives a better idea of the intention, but it looks like a fairly ugly hack.  I'd like to know if there's a good reason that there isn't a more legitimate alternative.

Comment: Why don't you measure it?  if you *can't* measure a difference, then there is none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your question is asking one thing, and then the body of your question is asking something else.  I can most certainly say your algorithm to test if a thread hold a lock will be very slow.  Much slower than just not checking.  Throwing exceptions like this is expensive.  Rule number one about exceptions.  **Don't use Exceptions for regular flow control in your program**.  Exceptions **are** a form of control flow structure, but you should only use them for error flow control.  Mainly because whenever you throw an exception it must gather up the stack trace to place that into the exception.  That is an expensive operation.  You should definitely use exceptions, but only for what they are designed for: error flow control.

If you want to test if the currentThread holds a lock you should use Thread.holdsLock(Object monitor)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock(java.lang.Object)

As for what is the cost of re-entering into a synchronize block for the currentThread is already a holder.  I don't have a very detailed answer for that.  I suspect its whatever the cost of calling holdsLock is.  That's probably the first check, and if it returns false then there is more cost with requesting this thread be add to the list of threads waiting on this object monitor.  If it's true it jumps right into the block.  Java threading, if it wants to be performant, the answer to this question better be fast as hell for the lock owner.  For threads not owning a lock its certainly more expensive.  If there is an answer to what the exact algorithm is I bet its in the "Taming Threads" book or Java spec.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the Thread method.  The point is that I have some shared logic between two or more methods.  The initial methods provide the synchronisation then the shared logic is executed. From my experience assertions are useful for describing (in code) the intention of the developer.  In my case actually synchronising on the monitor again gives the wrong impression as it implies the method can be called without first obtaining the lock.  The method should *never* be called without first obtaining the lock, so if it does it's a programming error.

Comment: I reread your question and I suppose its a little more clear.  You just want to know if you can use assert statements in those two methods rather than re-obtaining the lock again like in your first section of code.

Comment: I wouldn't do that if the methods were public, but for private methods using the assert will force the caller to lock so if someone refactored your code it will catch if they forgot to grab the lock.  I bet performance wise I bet its the same as using the synchronized blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Measure it. On my system there might not be a difference. On yours there might. The system you deploy to might be more different still.